# Show that a collection of subsets of aset is a subset of the Borel sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and put

$$ \mathscr{A} = \{ A \subset \mathbb{R} : \; \text{there exists} \; B \in \mathscr{B} \; \;  \text{with} \; f^{-1}(B)= A \} $$

Please show that $\mathscr{A} \subset \mathscr{B}$ (The Borel subset of the domain space $\mathbb{R}$).

$$ \mathit{Attempt}:$$

Let $A \in \mathscr{A}$ and choose $B \in \mathscr{B}$ with $f^{-1}(B) = A $. Since $B$ is a borel set (hence open ) and the continuity of $f$ implies that $f^{-1}(B) = A$ must be open. It follows that $\mathscr{A} \subset \mathscr{B} $.

Is this correct?

Question: Is the other direction true?

Comment: Borel sets need not be open. What you can do is trying to prove that $\scr A $ is a sigma-algebra containing the topology generated by the open sets. This will give you $\scr B \subset \scr A$, if true.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is not correct. A Borel set need not be open. For example, the set $(0,1]$ is Borel in $\mathbb{R}$, but not open.

However, your attempt has some pluses. You can follow these hints:

1) Just take $B$ to be open, instead of Borel

2) Use the fact that that the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra